# Starting new Activity from a Fragment with a button

Tags: java, android, button, android-activity, fragment

I'm new to Java and android and I'm having some issues.

I'm using navigation drawer activity with each menu item linked to a fragment. From the fragment, I'm trying to setup another menu using buttons that link to more Activities.

Here is my fragment that I want to link to more activities:

```
package com.notimportant


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class About extends Fragment {




    public About() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about, container, false);
    }

    Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonDevs);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DevsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

I'm getting these errors:

```
Error:(35, 30) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(35, 31) error: illegal start of type
Error:(35, 34) error: ')' expected
Error:(35, 39) error: ';' expected
Error:(35, 40) error: invalid method declaration; return type required
Error:(37, 28) error: ';' expected
Error:(37, 38) error: ';' expected
Error:(41, 6) error: illegal start of type
```

> rootView is highlighted red "Cannot resolve symbol rootView"
>
> setOnClickListener is highlighted red "Cannot resolve symbol
>   setOnClickListener"
>
> @Override is highlighted red... "Annotations are not allowed here"
>
> view is highlighted red "Cannot resolve symbol view"

My button id is `buttonDevs`. The activity I want to go to is called `DevsActivity`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put `Button` inside `rootView`.

Change this

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about, container, false);
    }

    Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonDevs);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DevsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

to this

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

      View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about, container, false);

     Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonDevs);
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DevsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: How would I go about adding more buttons to the same Activity, linking to different Activities?

Comment: Same as this `Button` you have create it on `xml` and then in java code you have Create `Intent` and `StartActivity` as you create in your code..

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about, container, false);
    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonDevs);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DevsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about, container, false);
}

Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonDevs);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DevsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

on this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about, container, false);

    Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonDevs);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DevsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your button inside `onCreateView()` like this -

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about, container, false);
        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonDevs);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DevsActivity.class);
              startActivity(intent);
           }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

your code must be inside the `onViewCreated()` method since you cant interact with the Views from `onCreateView()` method

```
 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View rootView, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonDevs);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DevsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
}
```

good luck